# Continuously watch for changes in Firebase

Tags: python, firebase

I'm trying to create a server that always has a connection open to my Firebase database to watch for changes and then perform a function (in my case, send a push notification). This question is concerned with how to keep an open connection.

I'd like to use Python for my server if possible. It seems like there's a nice Python wrapper for Firebase here: https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase

I can easily query my database now to return information, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to continuously watch for changes.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this Python wrapper uses REST API. In this case cannot use the core Firebase functionality which is attaching observers to data accepting real time callback functions.

Actually, I am now working on a similar script. In my case, I want to observe logs that we store in Firebase database. After a little bit of research I decided to do use nodejs to attach observer to Firebase data and write any new upcoming data to an external file which I can process later (Yes, I also prefer Python, so this is the reason I am only using nodejs to fetch the data from the database).

Here is a snippet from my script:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com");
var logsRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/logs");

var authToFirebase = function(loggedCallback) {
    ref.authWithPassword({        
        email: "user@example.com",
        password : "password"
    }, function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with uid " + authData.uid);
            loggedCallback();
        }
    })
}

authToFirebase(function() {
    //attaching child_added observer to logs
    logsRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {                
    }, function(errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject);
    });
});
```

As you can see it is quite simple. Notice that first I am logging in to an existing account, because the data I want to observe is not available to unauthorized users via Firebase rules mechanism.

I am using here "child_added" event, but you possibly want to adjust the type of event you want to observe to your needs.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response, I really appreciate it! So my logic would go inside `function(snap) { ... },`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. NodeJS API is the same as javascript API for Firebase and it is awesomely documented. You can check how to retrieve data here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: Great answer! Note that [Firebase also supports streaming event data over REST](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-03-24-streaming-for-firebase-rest-api.html). You can use the [python-sse package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sseclient/0.0.3) to consume that data and in that case won't have to poll.